# Application_Start is invoked frequently,

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, application-start

I had an issue that my **Cache** is being removed then added frequently, (i add it in the `Application_Start`) after some debugging i found that the method `Application_Start` is invoked almost every 10-20 mins, it seems like my application is being terminating frequently. Can anyone just give me a hint what could be the reason ?

*please ask for any missing information*

Comment: app pool recycling?.....

Comment: A really good point to consider, Thanks alot Mr. @MitchWheat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find your application pool associated with your website and your idle-timeout in your application pool and increase it if you don't want the `Application_Start` to fire every 20 mins (default). Check out the below screenshot and change the idle-timeout.

[image]